# How to refresh Fragment and pass info based on its position?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I`ve got an activity with ViewPager. There is 1 Fragment class - ScheduleFragment and a BroadcastReceiver in it. What I need is to get info and fill up the list in the fragment, based on its position.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
  super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
  ScheduleFragment scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
  return scheduleFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
  // Show 5 total pages.
  return 5;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
  return super.getItemPosition(object);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
  switch (position) {
    case 0:
      return getString(R.string.descr_monday);
    case 1:
      return getString(R.string.descr_tuesday);
    case 2:
      return getString(R.string.descr_wednesday);
    case 3:
      return getString(R.string.descr_thursday);
    case 4:
      return getString(R.string.descr_friday);
  }
  return null;
}
```

And here  the ScheduleFragment`s methods:

```
public ScheduleFragment newInstance(Integer day) {
    ScheduleFragment fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("day", day);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
  }
private class ScheduleBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      ArrayList<Lesson> result = (ArrayList<Lesson>) intent.getSerializableExtra("schedule");
      ArrayList<Lesson> dataToInsert = new ArrayList<>();
      Log.i("ASSSSSSSSSSSS", day.toString());
      for (Lesson lesson : result) {
        if (Objects.equals(lesson.getDay(), day)) {
          dataToInsert.add(lesson);
        }
      }

      adapter = new ScheduleListAdapter(context, result);

      SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter swingBottomInAnimationAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
      swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(schedule_listView);
      schedule_listView.setAdapter(swingBottomInAnimationAdapter);

      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }
```

I also have a Spinner in Toolbar with weeks. So also I want to update the fragment when I pick another week.
Please, guys. Help me. I`ve tried some solutions, but none of them helped me!

Hope for you assistance

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably not an expert on this, but I just completed a project full of fragments. The 'dirty' way I passed data between them was accomplished by using a singleton class in my project. This probably isn't the best solution, though.

For instance, my project included a fragment which I updated based on options in a settings activity. The FamilyMap (familyMap) class is my singleton, and I kept a settings model containing maps of needing information within that object. The code shown here is updating that settings model based on user interaction.

```
public void mapTypeSelection(String selection)
{
    Log.d("Map Selection", selection);
    switch(selection)
    {
        case "Normal":
            familyMap.getMapFrag().getmMap().setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            familyMap.getSettings().setMapType(new Pair<String, Integer>("Normal", GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL));
            break;
        case "Satellite":
            familyMap.getMapFrag().getmMap().setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            familyMap.getSettings().setMapType(new Pair<String, Integer>("Satellite", GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE));
            break;
        case "Hybrid":
            familyMap.getMapFrag().getmMap().setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            familyMap.getSettings().setMapType(new Pair<String, Integer>("Hybrid", GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID));
            break;
        case "Terrain":
            familyMap.getMapFrag().getmMap().setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            familyMap.getSettings().setMapType(new Pair<String, Integer>("Terrain", GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

//private method of your class
private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString)
{
    int index = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<spinner.getCount();i++){
        if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(myString)){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

public Pair<String, Integer> colorLineSelection(String selection)
{
    Log.d("Map Selection", selection);
    switch(selection)
    {
        case "Red":
            return new Pair<String, Integer>("Red", Color.RED);
        case "Blue":
            return new Pair<String, Integer>("Blue", Color.BLUE);
        case "Green":
            return new Pair<String, Integer>("Green", Color.GREEN);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch(parent.getId()){
        case R.id.mapTypeSpinner:
            mapTypeSelection((String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            break;
        case R.id.lifeLineSpinner:
            FamilyMap.getInstance().getSettings().setLifeColor(colorLineSelection((String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)));
            familyMap.getMapFrag().drawLines();
            break;
        case R.id.spouseLineSpinner:
            FamilyMap.getInstance().getSettings().setSpouseColor(colorLineSelection((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)));
            familyMap.getMapFrag().drawLines();
            break;
        case R.id.familyLineSpinner:
            FamilyMap.getInstance().getSettings().setFamilyColor(colorLineSelection((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)));
            familyMap.getMapFrag().drawLines();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The other thing I did was I retained the instance of my fragment - it was the main portion of my app, so it made sense for my situation. That allowed me to be able to update the original fragment when an option was selected. I also set the fragment to update when a certain result was reached by using startActivityForResult().

I think a better (cleaner, more acceptable) option for sending the data to your fragment would be object serialization, but at least in my case, that proved to be more work than I could afford at the time.

Hopefully this at least helps to point you in the right direction!

Comment: Dude, everything is so simple, you wont believe it! Can show you how I accidentally managed this!

Comment: You can watch my own answer to this, if you want. Hope, it will help you someday :)

Comment: Bundles are useful for storing primitive data, like what you put into your bundle. What I mentioned about serialization occurs when you have more complicated objects that you need to pass to activities, which is why I used a singleton - I didn't want to deal with serializing my objects. I'm glad bundling worked for you, though!

Answer (score 0):

So, after trying, trying and a lot of trying I figured it out!
In newInstance method, where I create new instance of Fragment I`ve added a bundle with day, according to fragments position

```
public ScheduleFragment newInstance(Integer day) {
ScheduleFragment fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("day", day);

fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
}
```

Then, in fragment's onCreateView I get this argument with `getArguments().getInt("day");` and put it into `private Integer dayglob;` field, which means, that its different for every fragment.
Now, when I have 'day' variable in my fragment I can put info into list according to provided day:

```
private class ScheduleBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      ArrayList<Lesson> result = (ArrayList<Lesson>) intent.getSerializableExtra("schedule");
      ArrayList<Lesson> dataToInsert = new ArrayList<>();
      for (Lesson lesson : result) {
        if (Objects.equals(lesson.getDay(), dayglob)) {
          dataToInsert.add(lesson);
        }
      }
      adapter = new ScheduleListAdapter(context, dataToInsert);

      SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter swingBottomInAnimationAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
      swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(schedule_listView);
      schedule_listView.setAdapter(swingBottomInAnimationAdapter);

      try {
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mScheduleBroadcastReceiver);
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.i("Unregister", e.toString());
      }
    }
  }
```

Every fragment got its own "onReceive" and wor on data from service for specific fragment.

Also, about the week spinner and updating the lists according to its value: I've made a static field `public static Spinner week_spinner;`, initialized it it onCreate method of my Activity and then, in fragment's "onCreateView" I made a request to my database like this: 
`requestQueue.add(connectionManager.getSchedule(this, savedUser.getGroup(), MainActivity.week_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1));`
The only matter thing here is getting value by accessing spinner via static reference.
And, also, I've set Listener which says to fragments something like

> Hey, guys! You are not up to date! Update yourself!

```
 week_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
});
```

And a little trick which make it possible is to change `getItemPosition`in FragmentPagerAdapter class (SectionsPagerAdapter in my case)

`@Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
      return POSITION_NONE;
    }`

It`s kinda tricky, I guess, but its the only way i can figure it out
I hope, this will help someone!